# not return populate value in nodejs and mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i have two `collection` .

**A**:`Manager`

```
 const ManagerSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  family: { type: String, require: true },
  userName: { type: String, require: true },
  phoneNumber: { type: String, require: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: true },
  isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  avatar: { type: String, default: null },
  scurityStamp: { type: String },
  locked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  lockedDate: { type: Date, default: null },
  accountFail: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

ManagerSchema.virtual('userRole',{
  ref : 'UserRole',
  localField : 'userRole',
  foreignField : 'user'
})
```

**B:**`UserRole`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserRoleSchema = Schema({
  role: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Roles' },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Managers'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserRole", UserRoleSchema);
```

now i need return the user with `UserRole` information . i write this code :

```
let auth=await Manager.findOne({userName:req.body.userName}).populate('userRole').exec();
```

but it not return the `UserRole` Information :

```
"isAdmin": true,
    "isDelete": false,
    "isActive": true,
    "avatar": null,
    "locked": false,
    "lockedDate": null,
    "accountFail": 0,
    "_id": "5f01dfc32714600aa8aa41bc",
    "name": "کیانوش",
    "family": "درتاج",
    "password": "$2b$15$WUgWTWuO/frlzWaGsfAHD.Jhp6ecqzL8Sr4g02B.XPceluXtJv0Z6",
    "phoneNumber": "0900018500ب98یdf0710bh06016",
    "userName": "kiadب0r0890037یh00f0072",
    "scurityStamp": "3db582c74dccbc628338bc8bcf62d405",
```

**how can i return the UserRole Information ????**

Comment: @RameshReddy yes it not worked

Comment: Your `ManagerSchema` doesn't have a local field called `userRole`.

Comment: @RameshReddyi create a virtual field

Comment: You're creating a virtual field but I don't think you can use the same as `localField`.

Comment: @RameshReddy how can i solve this prblem ?

Comment: Did you try setting the localField as `_id`? `localField : '_id'`

Comment: why did you have to use .virtual, why not just declare it just like the other regular fields?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you don't need to use 'virtual' then just declare a field normally.

but in your case, you need to indicate an existing/declared `localField` which matches the type of field you are pointing in the `foreignField` and which i believe is `role` not `user`:

```
const ManagerSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  family: { type: String, require: true },
  userName: { type: String, require: true },
  phoneNumber: { type: String, require: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: true },
  isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  avatar: { type: String, default: null },
  scurityStamp: { type: String },
  locked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  lockedDate: { type: Date, default: null },
  accountFail: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  role:{type: Object}
});

ManagerSchema.virtual('userRole',{
  ref : 'UserRole',
  localField : 'role',
  foreignField : 'role' // should match with the localField type
})
```

Comment: how  can i select custome field in output ?

Comment: i want return the `userRole` field `_id`

Comment: you can do `.populate('userRole','_id')`

Comment: i use the neasted populate `let auth = await Manager.findOne({ userName: userName }).populate({
            path: "userRole",
            model:'UserRole',
            populate:{
                path:'role',
                model:'Roles'
            }
          }).select('_id scurityStamp userRole._id');`

Comment: are you trying to get the _id of the document in the `userRole` collection or the _id of the role document that populates into the 'userRole'  collection ?